# Random Words with Chainlink VRF v2 not working as expected

Tags: solidity, blockchain, chainlink, goerli

I am using ChainLink VRF V2 - DIRECT FUNDING METHOD for getting a random number.

Source code

```
https://remix.ethereum.org/#url=https://docs.chain.link/samples/VRF/VRFv2DirectFundingConsumer.sol&optimize=false&runs=200&evmVersion=null&version=soljson-v0.8.7+commit.e28d00a7.js
```

When I use the function **requestRandomWords** it is returning only one random word. The **uint32 numWords = 2;** configuration should return 2 random words but returns only one.

*lastRequestId* shows only one id. Cross checked **requestIds** too but generates only one.

Let me know where am going wrong.

Code:

```
    // SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
// An example of a consumer contract that directly pays for each request.
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/ConfirmedOwner.sol";
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/VRFV2WrapperConsumerBase.sol";

/**
 * Request testnet LINK and ETH here: https://faucets.chain.link/
 * Find information on LINK Token Contracts and get the latest ETH and LINK faucets here: https://docs.chain.link/docs/link-token-contracts/
 */

/**
 * THIS IS AN EXAMPLE CONTRACT THAT USES HARDCODED VALUES FOR CLARITY.
 * THIS IS AN EXAMPLE CONTRACT THAT USES UN-AUDITED CODE.
 * DO NOT USE THIS CODE IN PRODUCTION.
 */

contract VRFv2DirectFundingConsumer is
    VRFV2WrapperConsumerBase,
    ConfirmedOwner
{
    event RequestSent(uint256 requestId, uint32 numWords);
    event RequestFulfilled(
        uint256 requestId,
        uint256[] randomWords,
        uint256 payment
    );

    struct RequestStatus {
        uint256 paid; // amount paid in link
        bool fulfilled; // whether the request has been successfully fulfilled
        uint256[] randomWords;
    }
    mapping(uint256 => RequestStatus)
        public s_requests; /* requestId --> requestStatus */

    // past requests Id.
    uint256[] public requestIds;
    uint256 public lastRequestId;

    // Depends on the number of requested values that you want sent to the
    // fulfillRandomWords() function. Test and adjust
    // this limit based on the network that you select, the size of the request,
    // and the processing of the callback request in the fulfillRandomWords()
    // function.
    uint32 callbackGasLimit = 50000;

    // The default is 3, but you can set this higher.
    uint16 requestConfirmations = 3;

    // For this example, retrieve 2 random values in one request.
    // Cannot exceed VRFV2Wrapper.getConfig().maxNumWords.
    uint32 numWords = 2;

    // Address LINK - hardcoded for Goerli
    address linkAddress = 0x326C977E6efc84E512bB9C30f76E30c160eD06FB;

    // address WRAPPER - hardcoded for Goerli
    address wrapperAddress = 0x708701a1DfF4f478de54383E49a627eD4852C816;

    constructor()
        ConfirmedOwner(msg.sender)
        VRFV2WrapperConsumerBase(linkAddress, wrapperAddress)
    {}

    function requestRandomWords()
        external
        onlyOwner
        returns (uint256 requestId)
    {
        requestId = requestRandomness(
            callbackGasLimit,
            requestConfirmations,
            numWords
        );
        s_requests[requestId] = RequestStatus({
            paid: VRF_V2_WRAPPER.calculateRequestPrice(callbackGasLimit),
            randomWords: new uint256[](0),
            fulfilled: false
        });
        requestIds.push(requestId);
        lastRequestId = requestId;
        emit RequestSent(requestId, numWords);
        return requestId;
    }

    function fulfillRandomWords(
        uint256 _requestId,
        uint256[] memory _randomWords
    ) internal override {
        require(s_requests[_requestId].paid > 0, "request not found");
        s_requests[_requestId].fulfilled = true;
        s_requests[_requestId].randomWords = _randomWords;
        emit RequestFulfilled(
            _requestId,
            _randomWords,
            s_requests[_requestId].paid
        );
    }

    function getRequestStatus(
        uint256 _requestId
    )
        external
        view
        returns (uint256 paid, bool fulfilled, uint256[] memory randomWords)
    {
        require(s_requests[_requestId].paid > 0, "request not found");
        RequestStatus memory request = s_requests[_requestId];
        return (request.paid, request.fulfilled, request.randomWords);
    }

    /**
     * Allow withdraw of Link tokens from the contract
     */
    function withdrawLink() public onlyOwner {
        LinkTokenInterface link = LinkTokenInterface(linkAddress);
        require(
            link.transfer(msg.sender, link.balanceOf(address(this))),
            "Unable to transfer"
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the address of your deployed contract or transaction hash of the failed tx on etherscan ? it's better to see if anything goes wrong there

Comment: https://goerli.etherscan.io/address/0x89508e01f5De0b2f41A688Ec00Ee53B56524C767
@minhhn2910

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's working correctly. Etherscan event log shows that your tx was successful and it return the single `request ID` [Etherscan link](https://goerli.etherscan.io/tx/0xfb1f3748f578a0781561396f42940a6dc28eb58ee7cbb28e7039666614701fee#eventlog) . For example the last requestID is `20537091100315528740606659648069392331019367734366926643103679361967052349730`. After the request, you need to wait a bit (e.g. 3 blocks), then the Chainlink Oracle contract will call back to your contract with function `fulfillRandomWords`, here is the tx they [callback to your contract after 4 blocks](https://goerli.etherscan.io/tx/0xc5a1db6181824cd6d4165bd77a5f905108e4d3158325e27a3f170fbe341083cd#internal) .

**After this callback**, you can get your two words random in `s_requests[_requestId].randomWords`. Basically to see your two random words of the above requestID you can call: `getRequestStatus(20537091100315528740606659648069392331019367734366926643103679361967052349730)` and the output :

```
0: uint256: paid 722301804963723361
1: bool: fulfilled true
2:uint256[]: randomWords 92086748116372425530428216044978222284806095875843674177268129041810438893537,
43771283264522314060226918666175388033006354411290591848280189310654619274589
```

Here `92086748...` and `4377128...` are the two words you requested.

To write custom logic to receive random words instead of querying `getRequestStatus`, you need to change the `function fulfillRandomWords` to process the randomness result after the line `s_requests[_requestId].randomWords = _randomWords;`.
Also, the `callbackGasLimit` should be adjusted if you request more words as stated in the comment.